# VBA Post Request From an API that requires Key

Tags: vba, ms-access, curl

I am new hear and really love how people are willing to help. I have an access database to manage student information and a separate website where students enroll their basic information. I create an api to either fetch xml or json format of the student info so i can import it to my database. Below is the curl of the api:
curl -F "apikey=d8a40f77-69b5-4ef7-b554-d8f86382101c" "http://ktsstf.org/call.php?apicall=registration.data&apiDataType=xml"

the curl command runs without a problem. However, my code in vba keeps giving me an error "fail: incorrect api key"
Below is the code and I really appreciate it if you guys can help me

```
Public Sub getscholar()
Dim webServiceURL As String
Dim actionType As String
Dim targetWord As String
Dim actionType2 As String
Dim targetWord2 As String

webServiceURL ="http://ktsstf.org/call.phpapicall=registration.data&apiDataType=xml"
      actionType = "Content-Type"
      targetWord = "text/xml"
      actionType2 = "Authorization"
      'targetWord2 = "apikey" + "d8a40f77-69b5-4ef7-b554-d8f86382101c"
      targetWord2 = "Basic " & ("d8a40f77-69b5-4ef7-b554-d8f86382101c")

    ' use late binding
      With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", webServiceURL, False
        .setRequestHeader actionType, targetWord
        .setRequestHeader actionType2, targetWord2
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
          Debug.Print .responseText
          MsgBox .GetAllResponseHeaders
        Else
          MsgBox .Status & ": " & .StatusText
        End If
      End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The -F parameter is for HTTP POST data.

You should modify your web service call to provide the apikey in your postdata instead of the Authorization header.